# Im trying to add tga textures but it's only turning the item green

Tags: modeling, texturing

i'm trying this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5YNJghc81U&ab_channel=TutsByKai) to help me build a 3d printable sword with colors. But when applying the texture its only getting it green like image one.

When i download it from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bWw7QDpC1Hg8t3dNQejw8nAgMfo5tkJj/view) it came with 3 textures. Can you guys help me?

[image: green].

Comment: Hi :). Make sure your object is properly UV unwrapped to display textures correctly

Comment: It would help to see how you added the textures in the shader and how the sword should look like. The sword in the FBX file is UV unwrapped and there are 3 textures. Normal, Mask (RGBA) and Diffuse (RGBA). It's hard to tell how to use the textures. The normal map is the only one that is clear. AFAIK normal maps are not 3d printable.